htaccess to perform https, www and drop trailing slash - produces //
I cant find anything that works 100%
i would like htaccess rules to

force www if not present
force https if http
strip off the last trailing slash

i know everybody is thinking we have seen this before and this is the usual reply but...
RewriteEngine on

## Force https and www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.test\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.test.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]

## Remove trailing slash if not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ https://www.test2.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

these are the results testing in https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/

http://test.co.uk = https://test.co.uk/ - not too worried about the trailing / here
https://test.co.uk = https://www.test.co.uk/ - ok
https://test.co.uk/page1/ = https://www.test.co.uk/page1/ - PROBLEM don't want the trailing /
https://www.test.co.uk/page1/ = https://www.test2.co.uk/page1 - works well

not only that but i host in IONOS and i get the following behavior...
when i go to

https://www.test.co.uk/page1/ it actually resolves to https://www.test.co.uk//page1 - i loose the trailing slash but it appears as a double ???

i am out of ideas, please help

Removed IIS tag, as it is not very irrelevant to IIS itself.

not very irrelevant - isnt that a double negative :) i will remove for you.

You must avoid redirecting multiple times for better SEO and faster response times.
You may use these rules in your site root .htaccess:
RewriteEngine On

## remove www, trailing slash and turn on https in same external redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,E=DSLASH:1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_DSLASH} =1 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?([^:]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]

Once you verify it is working fine, replace R=302 to R=301. Avoid using R=301 (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

thanks anubhava, you get similar results to me,
http://www.pondfolk.co.uk/test/ does not resolve to https://

That might be due to your old browser cache. I am testing these rules on my local apache (don't use any online test tool). It is redirecting http://www.pondfolk.co.uk/test111/ to https://www.pondfolk.co.uk/test111 so as you can see it added https and removed trailing slash. Make sure to test in a new browser or use some command line tool like curl / wget for testing.
